# Mongoose: How to update a numeric field by a percentage of that field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have this structure

```
{
name:"itemname",
price: 30
}
```

I want to reduce the price of items by e-g 10%, how would I go about it in Mongoose.

I've looked at $inc and $mul, both operate on field, so these cannot be used I guess e-g

```
{$mul: {price:0.10}}
```

Should update the price to 10% of original value, but I wanted to have it reduced by 10%.
So the operation I really want is

```
price = price - (price*0.10)
```

And I want that to happen in-place as there can be many many rows that are going to be affected.

Is there a Mongoos-ian way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce by 10% is the same as multiply by 0.9:

```
db.test.updateMany({}, {$mul: {price: 0.9}})
```